# Change Bokeh plot color outside of the plot area?

Tags: python, html, bokeh

I have a Bokeh plot that is embedded to an HTML page. Is there anyway to change the background color where the text of the x and y axis labels are?

I was able to change the plot's background with `plot.background_fill_color` but can't seem to find a property for the text

[Plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMaMu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `plot.border_fill_color`. This is documented here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#border